# NSManagedObject Parsing with RestKit Mapping

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, restkit

Here below is the code I am using for class:

```
@interface DBUser : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * accessToken;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * userID;
@end


@implementation DBUser
@dynamic username;
@dynamic email;
@dynamic userID;
@dynamic accessToken;
@end
```

here is my mapping:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DBUser class]];
userMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
[userMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"id", @"userID",
 @"email", @"email",
 @"username", @"username",
 @"access_token", @"accessToken",
 nil];

 [objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:userMapping withRootKeyPath:@"user"];
```

And route:

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:userMapping withRootKeyPath:@"user"];
```

Here is the json object that returns from service:

```
{
"user": {
"id": 1,
"username": "username",
"email": "email@email.com",
"access_token": "59f99efcffa9af7252d5ce1839082bd7e740e289e2577dda592c68647dc4e0db"
}
}
```

But in `objectDidLoad` method I am having some data failure:

```
<DBUser: 0x5939cc0> (entity: DBUser; id: 0x4f432e0 <x-coredata://6F302428-0538-41D0-9627-81C80E905DA8/DBUser/p11> ; data: <fault>)
```

Here I am attaching the complete log for the trace. It detects the object map it well but when i get `self` it do not show any data.

http://goo.gl/OcouL

What is wrong with this code or what I am missing in it?

Answer (score 1):

It is no data failure. The object is returned as FAULT. It does not mean that their is data failure. Try setting the returnsObjectsAsFaults property to NO.